# Which tools do you use in agile development especially Java Environment?

Tags: java, agile

I am searching tools for agile software development.
I use

- maven
- bugzilla
- jira
- hudson

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Isn't Bugzilla and JIRA pretty much the same?

Comment: We are using Bugzilla in Test Cycle. We put all test cases there

Comment: I would recommend using QuickScrum Agile project management tool - a permanently free version of the tool is available at http://www.quickscrum.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some tools to support some practices:

- xUnit tools family for testing
- [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) + [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) (alternatives: [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/)) for mocking
- [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) (alternatives: [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/), [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/)) for code coverage
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) for static analysis
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (alternatives: [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/)) for Continuous Integration
- [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) as QA dashboard
- [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.com/) (alternative: [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/)) for documentation and Knowledge Management
- [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/) (alternatives: [Crucible](http://www.cenqua.com/crucible/), [SmartBear](http://smartbear.com/codecollab.php)) for Code Review

But these are just tools, tools won't make you Agile by themselves.

Comment: For online relatime tasks estimating try http://www.planitpoker.com as well

Answer (score 5):

There's really too many to list and a lot depends on what you are building. Even then, there are usually multiple answer to the question.

- Building: Ant, maven, ...
- Code repo: SVN, CVS, Git, ....
- CI: Hudson, Cruise Control, Luntbuild, Bamboo, ...
- Testing: Junit, easymock, mockito, XmlUnit, HtmlUnit, ...
- Reporting: Cobertura, Emma, FindBugs, JavaDoc, ...
- Project management: XPlanner, GreenHopper, JIRA, ....
- Documentation: Confluence, XWiki, ....

Actually you might want to take a look at Atassian Studio.

Comment: +1 for Atlassian Studio. That stuff works very well together, and they are famous for quality support.

Answer (score 2):

- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [Planning Poker](http://www.planningpoker.com/)

Answer (score 1):

- [Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/) + [Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/)
- [Greenhopper (Jira plugin)](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/)

Answer (score 1):

[Mylen](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) Mylyn is the task and application life cycle management (ALM) for eclipse.

In summary tickets open closed all within eclipse makes life easier as the one interface deals with everything you get notified on ticket changes and it allows you to plan your development day better. Not sure it fits under Agile but it definitely fits as making development life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I got some More information about the Methods that can be considered during the Agile Development strategy

Following are the methods designed for Agile Development:

**DSDM** is probably the original Agile Development method. DSDM was around before the term Agile Development was even invented, but is absolutely based on all the principles we’ve come to know as Agile Development.

**SCRUM** is also an Agile Development method, which concentrates particularly on how to manage tasks within a team-based development environment.

**XP** (eXtreme Programming) is a more radical Agile methodology, focusing on the software development process and addressing the analysis, development and test phases with novel approaches aimed at making a substantial difference to the quality of the end product.

**DSDM** is probably the most complete Agile methodology, whereas SCRUM and XP are easier to implement and complementary because they tackle different aspects of development projects and are both founded on the same principles of Agile Development.

Above information may not be the answers, But I thought let me little knowledge

Comment: Good informations, thanks harigm.

Comment: 1) Scrum, XP, DSDM, Crystal, etc were **all** there before the term **Agile** was coined and **all** rely on what we call today the Agile values. 2) The first Scrum project was run in 1993 (and thus predates DSDM which was published in 1995). 3) The question is not about methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

- [H2](http://www.h2database.com)

A free SQL database engine written in Java. It has a nice console to query the DB, and can be nicely combined with liquibase for updates.

Comment: how does this relate to agile?

Comment: It has a nice console to query the DB, and can be nicely combined with liquibase for updates.

Answer (score 0):

- Eclipse
- P4
- Yoxel PCM